# Comparing SQL Date Time in Entity Framework by date parts

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have this query that was actually a view but I wanted to control the WHERE clause so I decided to tackle it by LINQ and EF6:

```
SELECT NULLIF(SUM([a].[REQUESTED_QTY]), 0) AS [Transaction],
       NULLIF(SUM([a].[ITEM_TOTAL]), 0) AS [Income]
FROM [dbo].[BILL_INFO_DETAIL] AS [a]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[SERVICE_INFO] AS [b]
        ON [a].[SERVICE_CODE] = [b].[SERVICE_CODE]
WHERE ([a].[INPUT_STATUS] = '1')
      AND ([b].[SERVICE_CODE] IN ( 1610, 1611, 1612 ))
      AND ([a].[PAY_MODE_ID] IN ( 1, 2 ))
      AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), a.STAMP_DATE, 101) IN ( '10', '11', '12' ))
      AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), a.STAMP_DATE, 102) IN ( '2017' ))
      AND ([b].[FEE] > 1)
```

After a while of trial and error, I got this conversion:

```
public async Task<ViewGuessOnline> GetGuessOnline(int[] serviceCodes, byte[] payModes, string[] months, string year)
{
    try
    {
        using (var context = new FinanceConnection())
        {
            var resultTemp = from a in
                    (from a in context.BILL_INFO_DETAILS
                        where
                            a.INPUT_STATUS == true &&
                            serviceCodes.Contains(a.SERVICE_INFO.SERVICE_CODE) &&
                            payModes.Contains(a.PAY_MODE_ID) &&
                            months.Contains(SqlFunctions.StringConvert(a.STAMP_DATE)) &&
                            (new[] {"2017"}).Contains(SqlFunctions.StringConvert(a.STAMP_DATE)) &&
                            a.SERVICE_INFO.FEE > 1
                        select new
                        {
                            a.REQUESTED_QTY,
                            a.ITEM_TOTAL,
                            Dummy = "x"
                        })
                group a by new {a.Dummy}
                into g
                select new
                {
                    Transaction = g.Sum(p => p.REQUESTED_QTY) == 0 ? (int?) null : (int) g.Sum(p => p.REQUESTED_QTY),
                    Income = g.Sum(p => p.ITEM_TOTAL) == 0 ? (decimal?) null : (decimal) g.Sum(p => p.ITEM_TOTAL)
                };

            // result = (await result.OrderByDescending(o => o.CustomerCode).ToListAsync()).AsQueryable();
        }

        Logger.Info($"{LayerName} -> {callerInfo.MethodName} -> Returning");
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        Logger.Error($"{LayerName} -> {callerInfo.MethodName} -> Exception [{exp.Message}]", exp);
        throw;
    }
}
```

I'm having an issue with the date part. In original SQL, the comparison of a Quarter 4 of 2107 is very easy. But I cannot find a proper inline linq conversion that translates to proper SQL.

Also, I had to use a dummy grouping even thoug there is not groups in the original SQL.

Comment: Haven't been able to try this but does this help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.datepart?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Data_Objects_SqlClient_SqlFunctions_DatePart_System_String_System_Nullable_System_DateTime__  and  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql

Comment: You don't seem to be aware of the [`DATEPART`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql) function and its C# counterpart in [SqlFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.datepart(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more wall-baning and I was able to make this work:

```
from a in
    (from a in db.BILL_INFO_DETAIL
        where
            a.INPUT_STATUS == true &&
            (new int[] {1610, 1611, 1612 }).Contains(a.SERVICE_INFO.SERVICE_CODE) &&
            (new int[] {1, 2 }).Contains(a.PAY_MODE_ID) &&
            a.STAMP_DATE != null &&
            (new int[] {10, 11, 12 }).Contains(a.STAMP_DATE.Value.Month) &&
            a.STAMP_DATE.Value.Year == 2017 &&
            a.SERVICE_INFO.FEE > 1
        select new
        {
            a.REQUESTED_QTY,
            a.ITEM_TOTAL,
            Dummy = "x"
        })
group a by new {a.Dummy}
into g
select new
{
    Transaction = g.Sum(p => p.REQUESTED_QTY) == 0 ? (int?) null : (int) g.Sum(p => p.REQUESTED_QTY),
    Income = g.Sum(p => p.ITEM_TOTAL) == 0 ? (decimal?) null : (decimal) g.Sum(p => p.ITEM_TOTAL)
}
```

I changed the method's parameter datatypes accordingly and this works now.